# WP7: Store data in users live account

Tags: windows-phone-7, live, account

For storing WP7-app-data it would be great if it was possible to use the current users live account. Is this possible somehow? I guess not. The alternative is for me to setup my own server to store the data, which means I also will have to implement account-management and require the user to create a new login and password for my particular app/site. This is not very practical as the user already has a live account on the phone. A compromise would be if I could use the logged in live-account on the phone as some kind of token to validate that the logged in user is who he/she pretends to be, and then store the data on my website. Comments?

Comment: I think most apps implement their own authentication at this point, which makes your question's outlook a little bleak.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for security reasons and I wouldn't expect it to change in the foreseeable future.

Allowing applications access to a users live account and be able to interact with content there would raise all sorts of possible issues, particularly around security.
On the phone the users data is sacrosanct and you (your app) cannot interact with it without the user knowing.

Comment: Yes but the stores would of course have to be separated so that only my app can access the files my app has created. I dont want my app to be able to read/write any files in the real user account. I just want the benifit of allready having a valid account being hosted by Microsoft. I should never have to reqiure my users to create even more accounts for the apps they use. If we could co-exist in the live-account (with some rules) it would be great, wouldnt it?

Comment: @Andreas Zita while this may be nice there are still lots of issues to consider which would make this difficult: Does the data have security issues about where it can be stored? What about size limits on how much can be stored (per user/per app)? How would you control access to the data from other sources (such as websites related to the app) as without this what would be the difference between using IsolatedStorage on the device other than it being slower to read/write from/to?
    
Given the choice, there are lots of other things I'd rather MSFT worked on first. :)